# How to validate file type in Orbeon Form

Tags: forms, validation, orbeon

I am trying to use Orbeon form builder where i want a field let say $control-1 as "Please upload form Here"

[image]

**I want to restrict user to upload only .pdf format file.**

I tried looking into "Validation and Alert" but dont know what shall I put in constraint.
It would be good if i can get some guidance around it.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering if you're using a rather old version of Orbeon Forms, as since version 2017.1 in the *Validation Type* column, you should see a drop-down from which you can select *Supported File Types*, as shown in the screenshot below. So, your solution here might be to upload to a newer version of Orbeon Forms.

[image: Ability to restrict uploaded file by content type]

See also: [Other common constraints](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/form-editor/validation#other-common-constraints)

Comment: Thanks @avernet! You are correct! We are currently using Older version. is there any other option on adding validation on file type?

Comment: You can add a formula that tests on `@mediatype`, like `starts-with(@mediatype, 'image/')`.

Comment: Thanks @avernet! I tried using the following formula but it still failed.

Comment: @AmanShah How does it fail exactly? Are you saying that when you upload a file that isn't an image the field isn't marked as invalid? ‑Alex